# Looking for a citation for a result of Littlewood

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, riemann-zeta

I see that it is proven by Hardy in 1914 that there are an infinite number of zeros on the critical line.  I also see that the Hardy and Littlewood conjectures appear in some papers they wrote together in 1921.  However, it was further proven by Littlewood alone that if $\gamma_n$ is an increasing sequence of the imaginary parts of the zeros on the critical line in the upper complex half-plane then

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\gamma_n-\gamma_{n-1}| =0 ~~.$$

Can someone please give me the citation for the paper in which Littlewood proved this result on his own?  I absolutely cannot find it!

Comment: You can now answer your own question! (Seriously - it is perfectly proper to do so.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Done!

Answer (score 3):

@Article{LW,
        author =       "J.E. Littlewood",
        title =        "Two notes on the {R}iemann {Z}eta-function",
        journal =      "Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc, 22, 3, 234-242 ",
        year =         "(1924)",}